# Is there a way to set batch size in host.json file for "extensionBundle" for an azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is there a way for me to set the batch size inside my host.json file with the "extensionBundle" key? Here is what it looks like:

```
"extensionBundle": {
"id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
"version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
}
```

I've seen some other people set it by doing this:

```
{
"extensions": {
  "queues": {
    "batchSize": 1,...
```

Though I'm not sure if things would break if I replaced the extensionbundle... Does anyone know how I'd access the bundle and change what I'd like to change? Or should I just replace the extensionBundle altogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Azure Functions, [Sample host.json file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#sample-hostjson-file) is made of all the possible options:**

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "aggregator": {
        "batchSize": 1000,
        "flushTimeout": "00:00:30"
    },
    "extensions": {
        "blobs": {},
        "cosmosDb": {},
        "durableTask": {},
        "eventHubs": {},
        "http": {},
        "queues": {},
        "sendGrid": {},
        "serviceBus": {}
    },
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
    },
    "functions": [ "QueueProcessor", "GitHubWebHook" ],
    "functionTimeout": "00:05:00",
    "healthMonitor": {
        "enabled": true,
        "healthCheckInterval": "00:00:10",
        "healthCheckWindow": "00:02:00",
        "healthCheckThreshold": 6,
        "counterThreshold": 0.80
    },
    "logging": {
        "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly",
        "logLevel": {
          "Function.MyFunction": "Information",
          "default": "None"
        },
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
              "isEnabled": true,
              "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond" : 20,
              "evaluationInterval": "01:00:00",
              "initialSamplingPercentage": 100.0, 
              "samplingPercentageIncreaseTimeout" : "00:00:01",
              "samplingPercentageDecreaseTimeout" : "00:00:01",
              "minSamplingPercentage": 0.1,
              "maxSamplingPercentage": 100.0,
              "movingAverageRatio": 1.0,
              "excludedTypes" : "Dependency;Event",
              "includedTypes" : "PageView;Trace"
            },
            "enableLiveMetrics": true,
            "enableDependencyTracking": true,
            "enablePerformanceCountersCollection": true,            
            "httpAutoCollectionOptions": {
                "enableHttpTriggerExtendedInfoCollection": true,
                "enableW3CDistributedTracing": true,
                "enableResponseHeaderInjection": true
            },
            "snapshotConfiguration": {
                "agentEndpoint": null,
                "captureSnapshotMemoryWeight": 0.5,
                "failedRequestLimit": 3,
                "handleUntrackedExceptions": true,
                "isEnabled": true,
                "isEnabledInDeveloperMode": false,
                "isEnabledWhenProfiling": true,
                "isExceptionSnappointsEnabled": false,
                "isLowPrioritySnapshotUploader": true,
                "maximumCollectionPlanSize": 50,
                "maximumSnapshotsRequired": 3,
                "problemCounterResetInterval": "24:00:00",
                "provideAnonymousTelemetry": true,
                "reconnectInterval": "00:15:00",
                "shadowCopyFolder": null,
                "shareUploaderProcess": true,
                "snapshotInLowPriorityThread": true,
                "snapshotsPerDayLimit": 30,
                "snapshotsPerTenMinutesLimit": 1,
                "tempFolder": null,
                "thresholdForSnapshotting": 1,
                "uploaderProxy": null
            }
        }
    },
    "managedDependency": {
        "enabled": true
    },
    "retry": {
      "strategy": "fixedDelay",
      "maxRetryCount": 5,
      "delayInterval": "00:00:05"
    },
    "singleton": {
      "lockPeriod": "00:00:15",
      "listenerLockPeriod": "00:01:00",
      "listenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00",
      "lockAcquisitionTimeout": "00:01:00",
      "lockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:03"
    },
    "watchDirectories": [ "Shared", "Test" ],
    "watchFiles": [ "myFile.txt" ]
}
```

Sample format of [extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue?tabs=in-process,extensionv5,extensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#host-json) in **`host.json`** to set the **`batch size`** is:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "queues": {
            "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
            "visibilityTimeout" : "00:00:30",
            "batchSize": 16,
            "maxDequeueCount": 5,
            "newBatchThreshold": 8,
            "messageEncoding": "base64"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my sample code for setting the **`batchSize`** in **`host.json`** file of the Azure Functions:

````
```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "batchSize": 1
    },
    "http": {
    "routePrefix": "api",
    "maxOutstandingRequests": 200,
    "maxConcurrentRequests": 1
    }
} }
````

No need to replace the **`extensionBundle`**, we need to set the required attributes in **`extensions`** block.

Another sample code example is like for storage queue trigger, to change frequency of the retry - `maxDequeueCount` value must be changed in **`host.json`** file and restart the function.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxDequeueCount": 1
    }
  }
}
```

---

Comment: Thank you so much for this response @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT . My goal with setting the batchSize to 1, was to stop concurrency in my blob storage trigger function. Will this do as I'm expecting? I've also limited my scale out capability of my function to 1.

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at props: maxConcurrentCalls, maxConcurrentSessions and set them to 1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp